# Failed to connect to local SQL Server using node

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server database using the following config:

```
var config = {  
          server: "localhost",   
          port:1433,
          user: 'sa',  
          password: 'sa',
          database: 'newarbete',   
    
         options: {
                trustedconnection:true,
         }
}
```

but I failed. I get this error

> Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

I can connect to the same db when it is on the server (changing the config parameters of course).

What is wrong with the config parameters for the local database, or what I should do to make work here?

Comment: Well `options.trustedConnection: true` is equivalent to Integrated Security, aka. Windows Authentication. See [Node mssql/tedious documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#tedious). Do you want to use SQL Login authentication (with a username and password) or Windows Authentication? Don't mix the two.

Comment: 1433 is usually the default instance. Do you have a default instance installed or do you have a named instance (which the Express edition usually installs)? Can you connect to your instance using SSMS running on the same machine as your failing application? If so, what values do you use to connect in SSMS?

Comment: Ssms ok with windows auth. But not working via app. I use there as ssms localhost,dB name and integritet security